# how image will fit on button

Tags: android, image, button

I am developing an app in which I am using a button. On the left side of button I am using an image. The problem is that image is large in size and is not fitting in size on button. How can I resize the image to make it fit on button. Plz give me some solution.
Xml is like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:weightSum="1" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/btn1" 
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
     android:layout_width="0dp" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_weight="1" 
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/blue" 
     android:gravity="left|center" 
     android:text="Wallpapers"/>
   </Linearlayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use different versions of your image and put them in the correct folders:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Hovewer, look this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html can help you